How to run cleaning up function when the first page disappears and initialization when the second page is shown
I am using jetpack compose in Android Kotlin development.
I am trying to set/reset listeners for each page in their corresponding viewModels. I thought I can, for example,

(1st page) LaunchEffect called bluetoothManager.setDeviceFoundListener(deviceFoundListener)
(1st page) DisposableEffect cleanup with bluetoothManager.setDeviceFoundListener(null)
(2nd page) do the same thing by creating its own
deviceFoundListener and setDeviceFoundListener(deviceFoundListener) in LaunchedEffect
(2nd page) cleanup listener by setting it to null in DisposableEffect
(continue for all following pages)

However, as step 3 happens before step 2, the listener was set to null when the user interacts with the second page.
May I know what will be a better approach to set/reset in this case?
Thank you in advance!
Here is what each viewmodel looks like:
  fun initTest() {
    bluetoothManager.setDeviceFoundListener(deviceFoundListener)
    bluetoothManager.setBondStateListener(bondStateListener)
    bluetoothManager.setConnectionStateListener(connectionStateListener)
  }


  fun resetTest() {
    bluetoothManager.setDeviceFoundListener(null)
    bluetoothManager.setBondStateListener(null)
    bluetoothManager.setConnectionStateListener(null)
  }

Each view call the functions by:
@Composable
fun MyFragment() {
  val viewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModel()
  LaunchedEffect(Unit) { viewModel.initTest() }
  DisposableEffect(Unit) { onDispose { viewModel.resetTest() } }
}

The BluetoothManager is doing:
  private var bondStateListener: BondStateListener? = null
  private var connectionStateListener: ConnectionStateListener? = null
  private var deviceFoundListener: DeviceFoundListener? = null

  fun setBondStateListener(listener: BondStateListener?) {
    this.bondStateListener = listener
  }

  fun setDeviceFoundListener(listener: DeviceFoundListener?) {
    this.deviceFoundListener = listener
  }


if you have same code repeating in each screen, have a shared viewmodel and add that code there and pass the data down.
